# undefined method +

Tags: ruby

What does this error mean? I am unable to get the conversion to work. miles are suppose to convert in to km and and km to miles. I'm wondering if i messed up on a calculation. Not sure how the call is not connected with the class... Thanks

the code

```
class Distance
@@value
@@unit


def initialize(value, unit)
    @@value = value
    @@unit = unit

end

def convert_miles_to_km(miles)
    return miles * 0.621371 
end

def convert_km_to_miles(km)
    return km * 1.60934
end


end

puts "Adding:"
d1 = Distance.new(1, "m")
d2 = Distance.new(1, "k")

puts d1 + d2

d1 = Distance.new(2, "M")
d2 = Distance.new(2, "m")

d3 = d1 + d2
puts d3
puts d3.value
puts d3.unit
```

Which the output should be:

```
Adding:
1.621371 Miles
4 Miles
4
m
```

when i run the script i get the error

```
C:\Users\Phillip\Desktop\Distance>ruby distance.rb
distance.rb:26:in `<main>': undefined method `+' for #<Distance:0x19c6008 @distance=1> (NoMethodError)
```

Answer (score 1):

It means what it says: the `Distance` class has no method `+`, so Ruby doesn't know how to add `d1` and `d2`. Ruby can't implement the method for you, you must program it yourself before you can add instances.

Answer (score 0):

```
d1 + d2
```

is equivalent to:

```
d1.+(d2)
```

It's simply a method call. Since `+` method is not defined in `Distance` class, you get the error.